# Вставить символ в строку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста.

Есть строка типа:

```
текст 123:123 текст 21.03.2019 текст текст текст текст текст
```

Нужно прогнать через PHP что бы получилось:

```
текст 123:123 текст (21.03.2019) текст текст текст текст текст
```

То есть обернуть дату скобками.

Помогите реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно организовать поиск двух групп символов, состоящих из: `<2-е цифры с точкой>`. После второй такой группы должны находиться четыре цифры. Весь шаблон, который совпадает с искомой подстрокой, необходимо сгруппировать в сохраняющих скобках для последующей передачи во второй аргумент функции `(в виде обратной ссылки)`:

```
$str = 'текст 123:123 текст 21.03.2019 текст текст текст текст текст';

$str = preg_replace('~((?:\d{2}\.){2}\d{4})~', '($1)', $str);

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = 'текст 123:123 текст 21.03.2019 текст текст текст текст текст';
$pattern = "/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/";

if (preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches)) {
    echo str_replace($matches[0], '('.$matches[0].')', $content);
}
```